# Omnipay Get transaction fee from stripe

Tags: laravel, omnipay

Ive been trying to return the transaction fee from stripe using `thephpleague/omnipay-stripe`.

Im not looking to return or set an application fee, but the actual fee that Stripe take off the for each transaction.

Heres my code so far:

```
if ($request->input('stripeToken')) {

    $gateway = Omnipay::create('Stripe\PaymentIntents');
    $gateway->initialize([
        'apiKey' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),
    ]);

    $token = $request->input('stripeToken');
    $paymentMethodId = $request->get('paymentMethodId');

    $response = $gateway->purchase([
        'amount' => session('cost'),
        'currency' => env('STRIPE_CURRENCY'),
        'description' => session('payment_title'),
        'paymentMethod' => $paymentMethodId,
        'token' => $token,
        'name' => \Auth::user()->name,
        'returnUrl' => route('customer.charge.stripe.return_url'),
        'confirm' => true,
    ])->send();


    if ($response->isSuccessful()) {

        $arr_payment_data = $response->getData();

        $data = [
            'type' => session('payment_type'),
            'cost' => session('cost'),
            'duration' => session('duration'),
            'description' => session('payment_title'),
            'transaction_id' => $arr_payment_data['id'],
            'status' => $arr_payment_data['status'],
            'fee' => // Whatever I need to call to get fee,
            'payment_details' => $arr_payment_data
        ];

        Payments::add_payment_to_db($data);

        $request->session()->forget(['cost', 'payment_title', 'duration']);

        return redirect()->route('customer.dashboard')->with([
            'status' => __('customer.payments.success'),
            'alert' => 'success',
        ]);


    } elseif($response->isRedirect()) {

        $response->redirect();

    } else {

        // payment failed: display message to customer
        return redirect()->back()->with([
            'status' => $response->getMessage(),
            'alert' => 'danger',
        ]);
    }
```

I've tried a few things but im not sure how to get the fee correctly.

Any help or ideas on how to get the fee would be grateful.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to retrieve the Payment Intent after the purchase has been successful in order to get the fee. I don't use Omnipay but maybe this method can help shoot you in the right direction. It's how I get the fee after a charge has been successful using the Stripe API.

```
protected function getFeeDetails($payment_intent_id, $user)
    {
        Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

        $payment_intent = PaymentIntent::retrieve([
            'id' => $payment_intent_id,
            'expand' => ['charges.data.balance_transaction'],
            ], 
            [
                'stripe_account' => $user->stripe_user_id
            ]);

        return $payment_intent->charges->data[0]->balance_transaction->fee;
    }
```